# How can HtmlHelper be used to create an external hyperlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In the same way that I can create an ActionLink in ASP.NET MVC that points to an action in a controller (e.g. - `@Html.ActionLink("MyDisplayText", "MyAction", "MyController")`), I would like to be able to create a hyperlink with an explicitly-defined, external url.

What I'm looking for is some code like `@Html.HyperLink("stackoverflow", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/")` that generates this HTML: `<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</a>`

If this isn't possible, I can always just write the HTML by hand.

(This is my first stackoverflow question. How exciting.)

Comment: Welcome aboard, please don't forget to up/down vote and mark answers as appropriate. You'll find out you'll get responses much better if your % of answers accepted is high.

Comment: Thanks! Up/Down votes require 15 reputation, so I can't do that just yet, but I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A custom helper could look like this:

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc {
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions {
        public static MvcHtmlString Hyperlink(this HtmlHelper helper, string url, string linkText) {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(String.Format("<a href='{0}'>{1}</a>", url, linkText));
        }
    }
}
```

May this be the first of many custom HtmlHelpers you use!

Comment: Thanks a ton! Your example produces the HTML: `&lt;a href=&#39;stackoverflow.com&#39;&gt;stack overflow&lt;/a&gt;`

Comment: I changed the return type to MvcHtmlString and it worked great.

Answer (score 14):

**This question is several years old and was intended as an answer for ASP.NET MVC v2. There are probably better, nicer ways to do this now, and I would strongly suggest that you consider looking at @jkokorian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8933002/31532). This just a nice way of showing what you *could* do, not what you *should* do!**

Nothing terribly new to add, but I tend to use `object` for optional params on HTML helpers, and add `new RouteValueDictionary(obj)` which turns them into a KVP which you can add with `MergeAttributes`.

**Code:**

```
public static class HtmlHelpers {
  public static MvcHtmlString ExternalLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string url, object innerHtml, object htmlAttributes = null, object dataAttributes = null) {
    var link = new TagBuilder("a");
    link.MergeAttribute("href", url);
    link.InnerHtml = innerHtml.ToString();
    link.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), true);

    //Data attributes are definitely a nice to have.
    //I don't know of a better way of rendering them using the RouteValueDictionary however.
    if (dataAttributes != null) {
      var values = new RouteValueDictionary(dataAttributes);

      foreach (var value in values) {
        link.MergeAttribute("data-" + value.Key, value.Value.ToString());
      }
    }

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
  }
}
```

**Usage in view:**

*Basic constructor:*

```
@Html.ExternalLink("http://www.example.com", "Example!")
```

*With Html attributes:*

```
@Html.ExternalLink("http://www.example.com", "Example!", new { title = "Example" })
```

*With HTML and data attributes:*

```
@Html.ExternalLink("http://www.example.com", "Example!", new { target = "_blank" }, new { id = 1 })
```

**Unit tests:**

```
[TestMethod]
public void ExternalLink_Example_ShouldBeValid() {
  //Arrange
  var url = "http://www.example.com";
  var innerHtml = "Example";

  //Act
  var actual = HtmlHelpers.ExternalLink(null, url, innerHtml);

  //Assert
  actual.ToString().Should().Be(@"<a href=""http://www.example.com"">Example</a>");
}

[TestMethod]
public void ExternalLink_Example_WithHtmlAttributes_ShouldBeValid() {
  //Arrange
  var url = "http://www.example.com";
  var innerHtml = "Example";

  //Act
  var actual = HtmlHelpers.ExternalLink(null, url, innerHtml, new { title = "Example!", @class = "myLink", rel = "external", target = "_blank" });

  //Assert
  actual.ToString().Should().Be(@"<a class=""myLink"" href=""http://www.example.com"" rel=""external"" target=""_blank"" title=""Example!"">Example</a>");
}

[TestMethod]
public void ExternalLink_Example_WithDataAttributes_ShouldBeValid() {
  //Arrange
  var url = "http://www.example.com";
  var innerHtml = "Example";

  //Act
  var actual = HtmlHelpers.ExternalLink(null, url, innerHtml, new { title = "Example!" }, new { linkId = 1 });

  //Assert
  actual.ToString().Should().Be(@"<a data-linkId=""1"" href=""http://www.example.com"" title=""Example!"">Example</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Old question: But simple answer - not sure if this was always a solution.

```
@Html.RouteLink("External Link", new {}, new { href="http://www.google.com" })
```

does the trick nicely - although possibly a little overkill.

Comment: Worked for me. thanks,  Could you also please advise how to modify it to open a new window?

Comment: @Html.RouteLink("External Link", new {}, new { href="http://www.google.com", target="_blank" })

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class HtmlHelpers    
{
    public static string Hyperlink(this HtmlHelper helper, string href, string text)
    {
        String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\">{1}</a>", href, text);
    }
}
```

Will work. Using this in the HtmlHelper denotes an extension method. Also if you want to be super cool MVC-ish style, you can use the TagBuilder and even supply options such as the target:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Script(this HtmlHelper helper, string href, string text, bool openInNewWindow = false)
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("a");
        builder.MergeAttribute("href", href);
        if(openInNewWindow)
        {
           builder.MergeAttributes("target", "_blank");
        }
        builder.SetInnerText(text);
        return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
```

Comment: extension methods need to be static and they must be declared in a static class

Comment: Thanks, was going off of memory.

Answer (score 0):

you need an html helper extension

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{ 
  public static string HyperLink(this HtmlHelper html, string text, string href) 
  {
    return string.Format(@"<a href="{0}">{1}</a>", href, text);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above solutions to work and did something much simpler.

CONTROLLER

```
Contracts model = db.Contract
ViewBag.Link = "<a href='" + model.Link + "'>View Link</a>";
```

VIEW

```
@Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.Link))
```